# def and return error in python2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function, return

Hey I'm working on a console game and I have a problem.Firstly the program should work as follows:
User chooses an attack power,
an attack with magnitude M will be successful with a chance of (100-M)%. That is, higher magnitude means higher risk of missing it. For instance, if M is 30, the chance of succeeding would 70%, whereas M if 10, the probability of succeeding would be 90%.If the attack is succesfull hp will decrease and the program will display hp's of players.I wrote something:

```
import random


def attack1():
    hp2=100
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "your chance of damaging", chance_of_damaging
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print "attack is succesful"
            hp2=hp2-attack_magnitute
            return hp2
        else:
            print "attack is unsuccesful"
            return hp2
print  attack1()


def attack2():
    hp1=100
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "your chance of damaging", chance_of_damaging
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print "attack is succesful"
            hp1=hp1-attack_magnitute
            return hp1
        else:
            print "attack is unsuccesful"
            return hp1
print attack2()
```

The program should continue to run until one of the hp values is equal zero
When I try to call the hp1 or hp2 variable, the value is deleted.

Can someone help me with where I made mistakes?I have to submit my project in 30 hours.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry,I didn't explain exactly.The codes is working but  program should continue to run until one of the hp values is equal zero.So I try to call attack1() and attack2() functions until one of the hp values is equal zero.
If you have chance of debug it,you will understand me.

for example in first attack: hp1 is decreasing 80 and, hp2=90 from 100.However program doesn't remember last value of hp's in second round.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So you want to keep looping through the attack funtions until one of the hp's are ==0 ?  Meaning, attack1 or attack2 may be called more than just once?

Comment: Yeah It is exactly.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the new main funtion at the bottom, the hp values are passed in and returned instead of being reinitialized at the beginning of the attack functions. The loop continues until one of the hps is <= 0

```
import random


def attack1(current_hp):
    hp2=current_hp
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "your chance of damaging", chance_of_damaging
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print "attack is succesful"
            hp2=hp2-attack_magnitute
            return hp2
        else:
            print "attack is unsuccesful"
            return hp2



def attack2(current_hp):
    hp1=current_hp
    chance_of_damaging=random.randint(0,100)
    print "your chance of damaging", chance_of_damaging
    while True:
        attack_magnitute=input("Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: ")

        if attack_magnitute > 50:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."

        elif attack_magnitute < 1:
            print "The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50."
        else:
            break


    while True:
        if chance_of_damaging > attack_magnitute:
            print "attack is succesful"
            hp1=hp1-attack_magnitute
            return hp1
        else:
            print "attack is unsuccesful"
            return hp1
def main():
     hp1, hp2 = (100,100)
     while hp1 > 0 and hp2 > 0:
        hp1 = attack1(hp1)
        hp2 = attack2(hp2)
main()
```

EDIT:
If you want to print out the final state of hp1 and hp2 make your def main() like this:

```
def main():
     hp1, hp2 = (100,100)
     while hp1 > 0 and hp2 > 0:
          hp1 = attack1(hp1)
          hp2 = attack2(hp2)
     print "Final State of hp1: " + str(hp1)
     print "Final State of hp2: " + str(hp2)
```

Comment: You could also get rid of the other attack method since the only differentiating factor is the hp as inner state. You could just have one attack() method and make two calls to it in the main loop. Just pass in the different hp values for each call.

Comment: my guess is that you are trying to call  hp1 or hp2 out of scope.  Make sure you print the values of hp1 and hp2 within the main() function.

Comment: after each attack you want to display the current hp?

Comment: Yes,I did it.Thank you so much for your helps.